# React — pass checkbox checked state to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a  component with a clickHandler inside. I'd like to pass that state to the checkbox's parent component, but I'm not quite sure how to grab it from the checkbox component.

FIDDE: https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/7km493bd/4/

**Here is the checkbox component:**

```
import React from 'react';

class CheckOnOff extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
  }
  render() {
    const text = this.state.checked ? 'On' : 'Off';
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" className="on-off-switch" id={this.props.id} ></input>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id} onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

module.exports = CheckOnOff;
```

**Here is the parent component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckOnOff from 'CheckOnOff';

const Settings = () => (
  <div id="settings">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Auto Sleep:</span>
        <span>{text} from auto_sleep instance</span>
        <CheckOnOff id="auto_sleep" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Auto Light:</span>
        <span>{text} from auto_light instance</span>
        <CheckOnOff id="auto_light" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

export default Settings;
```

Comment: Facebook uses `onChange` prop for that.

Comment: You can give your children a callback function of the parent, that will be called inside handleClick of the checkbox component

Comment: Not sure how to form the syntax. I added a fiddle above.

Answer (score 1):

I introduce the handleChange function in the parent component, just a console.log to see what checkbox is updating and its status

```
class CheckOnOff extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    this.props.handleChange(this.state.checked);
  }
  render() {
    const text = this.state.checked ? 'On' : 'Off';
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" className="on-off-switch" id={this.props.id}></input>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id} onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
      )
  }
};

const Parent = () => {

  const handleChange = (name, isChecked) => {
    console.log(name, isChecked);
  }

  return (
    <div id="settings">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Auto Sleep: is turned (text from child instance) </p>
          <CheckOnOff id="auto_sleep" handleChange={handleChange.bind(this, 'checkBox1')}/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Auto Light: is turned (text from child instance) </p>
          <CheckOnOff id="auto_light" handleChange={handleChange.bind(this, 'checkBox2')}/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```